# Password_resets table missing, even after doing php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am trying to do password recovery in laravel, but after inserting an email to send the reset request, an error appears saying that password_resets doesn't exist.

I've already tried to migrate again but nothing works.

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "password_resets" does not exist 
LINE 1: delete from "password_resets" where "email" = $1 ^ (SQL: delete from "password_resets" where "email" = blabla@gmail.com)
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/artisan-migrate-password-reset-table?page=1), it seems that the command to generate the migration for password_resets no longer exists, you can try to create a new migration with this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token')->index();
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('password_resets');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one question, in which paste should I create this file?

Comment: Create a migration with `php artisan make:migration CreatePasswordResetsTable ` and paste the code in the file that is created and then run the migration.

Comment: Just tried that and this error appeared:
```PHP
file_put_contents(/home/joao/lbaw1865/database/migrations/2019_06_03_232630  
  _create_password_resets_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or   
  directory
```

Comment: Try clearing all the cache `php artisan cache:clear, php artisan view:clear, php artisan route:clear, composer dump-autoload`, and after that, run the migration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed the issue of the missing table by adding these two lines in AppServiceProvider.php.

**Follow these steps:-**

1. Open **AppServiceProvider.php** (Location: **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**).
2. Add this line outside from classes `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`
3. Add this line inside **function boot()** `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`
4. **Delete** all tables from database.
5. **Run** this command `php artisan migrate`

```html
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```